# How to get title and description data from XML file

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I'm trying to write data to a text file in this format:

```
Channel|Date|Start time|Duration|Title|Desc
```

Here is XML example:

```
<!-- language: xml -->
<tv>
  <channel id="YLE TV1">
    <display-name lang="fi">YLE TV1</display-name>
  <programme start="20150828110000 +0300" stop="20150828110500 +0300" >channel="YLE TV1">
    <title lang="fi">Yle Uutiset</title>
  </programme>
  <programme start="20150828110500 +0300" stop="20150828111200 +0300" >channel="YLE TV1">
    <title lang="fi">Yle Uutiset Uusimaa</title>
    <desc lang="fi">Uutisia Uudeltamaalta.(n)</desc>
  </programme>
</tv>
```

Here is my Ruby code:

```rb
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'

open('myfile.out', 'a') do |f|
  doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open("guidetv1.xml"))
  doc.css("programme").each do |response_node|

    strChannel = response_node["channel"]
    if(strChannel.eql? "YLE TV1")
      strChannel = "1"
    elsif(strChannel.eql? "YLE TV2")
      strChannel = "2"
    end
    strStart = response_node["start"]
    strStop = response_node["stop"]
    strTitle = response_node["title"]
    strDesc = response_node["desc"]
    f.puts strChannel + "|" + strStart + "|" + strStop + "|" + strTitle + "|" + strDesc
  end
end
```

How can I read `title` and `desc` data? 
And how to check that is `Desc` exists?

Comment: Unfortunately your post is unreadable due to wrongly formated XML example. Please check [Markdown help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and make sure to check post after submitting for formatting errors.

Comment: Your "text file" is a variant of a CSV ("Comma Separated Value") file. Look at Ruby's CSV class, and figure out how to tell it to use `|` instead of a comma between fields. It'll handle all sorts of corner cases you haven't thought of.

Comment: What are `String strChannel` and similar lines? That's not Ruby.

Comment: Your XML is invalid. `<programme start="20150828110000 +0300" stop="20150828110500 +0300" >channel="YLE TV1">` isn't syntactically correct. Nokogiri will attempt to do a fix-up which will change the XML.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested code. The XML was tweaked to make it syntactically correct. Read the [CSV](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/index.html) and [Date/DateTime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/index.html) or [Time](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/time/rdoc/index.html) documentation to finish the code where marked.

```
require 'csv'
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<tv>
  <channel id="YLE TV1">
    <display-name lang="fi">YLE TV1</display-name>
  <programme start="20150828110000 +0300" stop="20150828110500 +0300" channel="YLE TV1">
    <title lang="fi">Yle Uutiset</title>
  </programme>
  <programme start="20150828110500 +0300" stop="20150828111200 +0300" channel="YLE TV1">
    <title lang="fi">Yle Uutiset Uusimaa</title>
    <desc lang="fi">Uutisia Uudeltamaalta.(n)</desc>
  </programme>
</tv>
EOT

CSV.open(
  'file.csv', 'wb', 
  quote_char: '|', 
  headers: ['Channel', 'Date', 'Start time', 'Duration', 'Title', 'Desc']
) do |csv|
  doc.search('programme').each do |programme|
    channel = programme['channel']
    date = programme['start']       # => further processing needed
    start_time = programme['start'] # => further processing needed
    stop_time = programme['stop']   # => further processing needed
    duration = 0                    # => further processing needed
    title = programme.at('title').text
    desc = programme.at('desc').text || ''

    csv << [channel, date, start_time, duration, title, desc]
  end
end
```